# How to get a variable value outside of it's class

Tags: php, function, magento

I want to get the value of a variable `$var` outside of its class (I am on a *Magento* platform if that matters).

```
class CheckDelivery_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction() {
        $var = '452001';  # $var variable wanted to get value outside it's scope of class 
        // some conditions here..
        return $var;
        exit;
    }
}

echo $var;   # wanted to call $var outside the class
```

In the above example I want to get the value of `$var`, which is a variable that was defined inside a function in a class.

This doesn't work though, so how can I do this?

Comment: create global variable if you want to access outside the class

Comment: `$var` lives within the scope of `indexAction`

Comment: don't understand, why do you want to call `$var`, you need to call `indexAction()` function instead

Comment: "calling" a variable does not have any meaning.

Comment: Can you tell us, why do you need this? You can get the value of the variable from a function.

Comment: I want to use the value that is stored in $var, but outside of the class. As i am sending this data as request to a API. Code outside the Class is.. $request['RequestedShipment']['Recipient']['Address']['PostalCode'] = $zip;

Comment: I have tried setting as global $var; $var= '452001'; but still can't access the variable out the class.

Comment: There are *variables* and *globals*. *Variables* have a finite lifespan which is defined by the *scope* they live in. This *scope* is usually the *code block* they are declared in. If you wish to gain a better understanding of how a variable's lifetime is defined and how it differs from globals, read up on these terms, they're basic principles.

Answer (score -1):

As the comments said, make it global or better static (if you want to share the value across all instances):

```
class CheckDelivery_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public static $var;

    public function indexAction() {
        self::$var = '452001';
        // ...
        return self::$var;
    }
}

echo CheckDelivery_IndexController::$var;
```

btw. your `exit;` after the return statement is useless

Comment: Hi, tried it exactly. echo CheckDelivery_IndexController::$var; doesn't have any values. any idea?

Comment: The variable will get its value after the first call of the  `indexAction ()` method.

Comment: yes, but CheckDelivery_IndexController::$var out side the class is not getting any value. thanks.